# JQuery function does not work properly after refactoring

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery (more C#) and cant see what I am doing wrong here.

I have the following JQuery which toggles a hamburger menu and also puts a dimmer effect and prevents scrolling to the Body. The hamburger also animates from the 3 horizontal lines to an X. In the first JQuery (below) this works fine. However I have been trying to refine this and clean up my code to the second JQuery below which looks a lot cleaner to me (bearing in mind future functions). However when I do this everything still works as intended apart from the hamburger no longer animates to a X. I really cannot see why as there is no real discernible difference, to my newbie JQuery eye anyway.

Also as a newbie I would also love to know if the following 2 lines of code are even needed in a function like this:

```
e.preventDefault();

event.stopPropagation();
```

JQuery (Works):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
            jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
            jQuery('.hamburger ul').toggleClass('active');
            jQuery('.dimmer').toggleClass('active');
            jQuery('body').toggleClass('no-scrolling');

            e.preventDefault();            
    });
});
```

JQuery (Doesn't work):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
    toggleNav();

    function toggleNav() {
      event.stopPropagation();
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
      jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
      jQuery('.hamburger ul').toggleClass('active');
      jQuery('.dimmer').toggleClass('active');
      jQuery('body').toggleClass('no-scrolling');

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `event.stopPropagation()` it should be `e.stopPropagation()`. Also, moving your code to a new function, which is defined within the event handler itself, seems kind of silly, as that function will be redefined every time you click...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realise that was what I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple issues. You were defining the function inside of the click event and calling it directly. Because of this your `this` variable is scoped incorrectly for what you need. This also means that every time you click `#toggle-nav` the function is created, called, and then destroyed. If you declare it outside of the click event it is only created once will be reused for each click instead. You were also using `event.stopPropagation()` while the argument name you were using was `e`. Finally, you do not need to pass an anonymous function into the `.click` function. You can pass a named function, by name, and it will be called directly.

Here is your code cleaned up a little to resolve these issues.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(toggleNav);

    function toggleNav(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.hamburger ul').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.dimmer').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('body').toggleClass('no-scrolling');

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can just use an anonymous function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.hamburger ul').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.dimmer').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('body').toggleClass('no-scrolling'); //Alternatively : jQuery(document.body)

        return false;
    });
});
```

Regarding the use of `event` AND `e`, see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). Essentially the `event` property exists on the global context for some browsers. Which means your code may function in those browsers but it will break in others. Click events automatically pass the event as the first argument to the supplied function so you have direct, cross-browser access to it there.

As a final note, when using jQuery events `return false;` fires both `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.preventDefault();` so you dont need to call them yourself if you return false.

[jQuery source for reference](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b442abacbb8464f0165059e8da734e3143d0721f/src/event.js#L340)

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic and has helped me so much to understand what is going on. Its also made me realise how little I know about JQuery and how different it actually is to c# (which is my day job but still have a long way to go on too)! Would doing what you have done, and what I had tried to do, be correct i.e in that its better to create a function separately and call it rather than defining the function inside of the click event?

Comment: Glad I could help :) Generally if you are only using the function once I don't think it hurts to just use an anonymous function. I edited my answer to include an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, the value of `this` refers to the `#toggle-nav` element. In the revised version, `this` refers to its parent function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and again this has pointed out something that I didn't realise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your function out of the event listener.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    toggleNav();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

function toggleNav() {
  jQuery('#toggle-nav').toggleClass('active');
  jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
  jQuery('.hamburger ul').toggleClass('active');
  jQuery('.dimmer').toggleClass('active');
  jQuery('body').toggleClass('no-scrolling');
}
```

I also added the correct selector to the function, since `this` changes. You could pass in the event target if you want (`e.target` maybe, I can't recall off the top of my head). And to answer your last question, I suspect you don't the the two lines in question, but without looking at all your code, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going to accept Maria's answer but just wanted to say thanks as all the answers so far have made me realise something new.